# Futex Syscall in C Always Returns errno 14

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, futex

Every time I try to make a `futex`-related system call in C, I get a return value of `-1` and `errno = 14` **(EFAULT - Bad Address)**.

First I adapted code from the futex manpage. [Futex Manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man2/futex.2.html#errors)

My changes are small and are as follows:

- Print futexes

```
       static void
       fwait(int *futexp)
       {
           printf("%p\n",  futexp);
           printf("%d\n", *futexp);
           int s;
```

- Deadlock the processes by commenting out unlock logic.

```
// fpost(futex2);
...
// fpost(futex1);
```

The altered program printed the following:

```
0x7f9e696b3004
0x7f9e696b3000
1
0
Parent (88542) 0
0x7f9e696b3004
0
```

While the code is running, I ran `strace -p 88542` to verify the address of the futex.

```
strace: Process 88542 attached
futex(0x7f9e696b3004, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL
```

Notice that 0x7f9e696b3004 appears in both outputs.

Finally, I attempted to call `FUTEX_WAKE` on the futex. I used this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define futex(a, b, c, d, e, f) syscall(SYS_futex, a, b, c, d, e, f)

int main(void)
{
int rc;

  uint32_t *uaddr =  (uint32_t *)0x7f9e696b3004;
  printf("%p", uaddr);
  printf("\n");

  rc = futex(uaddr, 1, 0, (const struct timespec *)0, (int *)0, 0);
  printf("rc=%d\n", rc);
  printf("Value of errno: %d",errno);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;
} // main
```

Adapted from [Mngt_futex_kernel](http://www.rkoucha.fr/tech_corner/the_futex.html#Mngt_futex_kernel)

The result is

```
sudo ./fwake.out
0x7f9e696b3004
rc=-1
Value of errno: 14
```

I have tried identifying the physical address associated with the logical address. In this case, it is `0x1ae8101004`. The result is still `errno = 14`.

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: Why do you think you can use the futex address from one program in a completely unrelated program? Addresses are per-process.

Comment: I expected that making the syscall with the virtual address would not work. I hoped that translating the virtual address to the physical address would. I forgot that making the syscall on that address means I made the call on that address in the virtual address space of the second process.

Comment: User-mode processes never deal with physical addresses. Except for memory-mapped hardware ports, physical addresses are assigned dynamically by the MMU and change all the time.

Comment: I even considered translating the physical address to the virtual address space of the second process. I then realized that if there is not shared memory, then there may not be a virtual address to point to the physical address.

Comment: Exactly. If you want to share a futex between processes, you need to use shared memory.